# Update swipeEnabled prop dynamically in React Navigation MaterialTopTabNavigator (v5)

Tags: react-native, react-native-navigation, react-navigation-v5

I'm currently struggling with dynamically updating the swipeEnabled prop in `@react-navigation/material-top-tabs` v5. What I've tried is having a global state which dictates whether the tabs should be swipeable or not. The `isSwipeable` value is beeing updated from within a screen in the TabNavigator. In this case when pressing a LineChart. My code:

```
const { isSwipeable } = useContext(GlobalContext)

 return (
    <TopTab.Navigator swipeEnabled={isSwipeable} tabBar={(props) => <TabBar {...props} />}>
         <TopTab.Screen
             name="Screen1"
             component={Screen1Component}
             options={{
                 tabBarLabel: 'Screen1',
                 tabBarIcon: () => null
             }}
         />
        <TopTab.Screen
            name="Screen2"
            component={Screen2Component}
            options={{
                tabBarLabel: 'Screen2',
                tabBarIcon: () => null
            }}
        />
    </TopTab.Navigator>
)
```

But this doesn't dynamically update the `swipeEnabled` prop for the Tab Navigator.

I've also tried by using something like from within a tab screen:

```
 React.useLayoutEffect(() => {
    
    navigation.setOptions({})
}, [navigation])
```

But here in the `setOptions` I can only change the tabLabel, tabIcon etc. which doesn't help me much.

Comment: Did you find a solution to this? Encountered the same problem, was going to try using React Context but seems like you did not have much success with that.

Comment: @Joe No sorry. Just went with no swipe in the tabs because I couldn't figure this out